# Image moves too quickly with touch

Tags: android, touch, surfaceview

I am trying to do a simple task. I have a circle starting in the top left corner of a screen. When I touch anywhere on the screen, I want the circle to slowly move towards and stop on the spot the user touched. I have successfully implemented this, however the circle moves way too fast. I believe that I need to try to put my run() thread to sleep for a few milliseconds, but I cannot seem to do this successfully. What would be the solution to this? Code is simple, but I posted below just in case, thank you for the help in advance!

```
Thread t = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean isItOK = false;

    public GameView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        holder = getHolder();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
        int screenArrayWidth = screenWidth / 50;
        int screenArrayHeight = screenHeight / 30;
        int[][] mapArray = new int[50][30];

        while (isItOK)
        {
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
            {
                continue;
            }
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);



            c.drawBitmap(ball, destinationX - (ball.getWidth() / 2),
                    destinationY - (ball.getHeight() / 2), null);


        }
    }


public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me)
{
    switch (me.getAction())
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    {
        while (((int)(me.getX()) != (int)(destinationX)) && ((int)(me.getY()) != (int)(destinationY)))
        {
            if (me.getX() > destinationX)
            {
                destinationX++;

            }

            if (me.getX() < destinationX)
            {
                destinationX--;

            }

            if (me.getY() > destinationY)
            {
                destinationY++;

            }

            if (me.getY() < destinationY)
            {
                destinationY--;

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Adding Thread.sleep() to the run loop doesn't help? And you do unlockAndPost after each bitmap drawing it just escaped from the code snippet, right?

Comment: Yes, I tried Thread.sleep() at several intervals of time, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. And yes, I have the unlockAndPost() method, but I left it out on accident

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem that you are running into is that you are not taking elapsed time into account.  This also means that the animation will move at different speeds on different devices and with different things running in the background.  What you need to do is decide how many pixels per millisecond you want the circle to move and then modify the movement distance by the time elapsed since the last frame.

Comment: A Linear Interpolator might also help.